# How do I return new Backbone instance from class function

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, coffeescript

I want the ability to get a random Book model like:

```
book = App.Models.Book.random()
```

I've got the following Backbone.js model (in CoffeeScript)

```
class App.Models.Book extends Backbone.Model
  @random: ->
     $.getJSON "/books/random", (data) ->
       new App.Models.Book
         author: data['author']
         title: data['title']
```

But, as I'm sure you can tell, @random is returning the jqXHR object, not the instance. I have checked and `data` is correct inside of my callback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is (Java|Coffee)Script where everything is done using callbacks. You wouldn't return the random book from `App.Models.Book.random`, you'd give it a callback function:

```
class App.Models.Book extends Backbone.Model
  @random: (callback) ->
     $.getJSON "/books/random", (data) ->
       book = new App.Models.Book
         author: data['author']
         title: data['title']
       callback?(book)
```

and then to use it:

```
App.Models.Book.random (book) ->
  # Do something useful with book in here
```

Your `random` class method would still be returning the `jqXHR` if the caller wanted access to all the usual fancy AJAX hooks.

Comment: Thanks so much. Brain was dead last night.

Answer (score 1):

Call

```
book = App.Models.Book.random()
```

In class

```
class App.Models.Book extends Backbone.Model

  @random: ->
    temp = new App.Models.Book()
    temp.url = "/books/random"
    temp.fetch {wait: true}  # or whatever parameters you want
```

That should do your work.

But for me, I would prefer a non class function way.

```
book = new App.Models.Book()
book.getRandomData()
```

in Class

```
class App.Models.Book extends Backbone.Model

  getRandomData: =>
    @url = "book/random"
    @fetch {wait: true}
```